Error:"Required parameter WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is missing" raised although I deploy function onto a deprecated asp
I am deploying a python azure function onto an ASP with SKU of P1V3
I used to use a connection string of WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and it worked well.
Now, as security concerned, I want to migrate it to managed identity.
The bicep looked like:
resource sampleFunctionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: uniqueSampleFunctionName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp,linux'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned, UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${umi.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: 'Python|3.9'
      appSettings: {
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName'
          value: storage.name
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: toLower(uniqueSampleFunctionName)
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~14'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appi.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: functionWorkerRuntime
        }
        {
          name: 'EventHubConn__fullyQualifiedNamespace'
          value: '${eventHubNamespaceName}.servicebus.windows.net'
        }
        {
          name: 'EventHubConn__tenantId'
          value: '72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47'
        }
        {
          name: 'EventHubConn__clientId'
          value: umi.properties.clientId
        }
        {
          name: 'CosmosConn__accountEndpoint'
          value: 'https://${cosmosdbName}.documents.azure.com:443/'
        }
        {
          name: 'CosmosConn__tenantId'
          value: '72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47'
        }
        {
          name: 'CosmosConn__clientId'
          value: umi.properties.clientId
        }
      ]
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
    }
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}

However, error raised :
[{"code":"BadRequest","target":"/subscriptions/e2108557-56b7-4d88-88e4-fdc4f0468d32/resourceGroups/wcx-rg-equal-mas-apps-dev/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/mas-sample-func-lmyvtb5moi22y","message":"{\r\n  \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"Message\": \"Required parameter WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is missing.\",\r\n  \"Target\": null,\r\n  \"Details\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"Message\": \"Required parameter WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is missing.\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"Code\": \"BadRequest\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"ErrorEntity\": {\r\n        \"ExtendedCode\": \"01010\",\r\n        \"MessageTemplate\": \"Required parameter {0} is missing.\",\r\n        \"Parameters\": [\r\n          \"WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n        \"Message\": \"Required parameter WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is missing.\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Innererror\": null\r\n}"}]}}

After checking this document, WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING 
I found the appsetting of WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING can be straightly removed in the deprecated ASP.
As I am using an ASP with SKU P1V3, I believe there is no need to setup the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING.
Did I miss anything important?
Is the appsetting of WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING still necessary in my case?

The same is coming for me when deploying your code. Image. @jiana

With all the Api versions I tried, WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is the must to be used setting when deploying the above service. The implementation without this setting is still not working. @jiana

Thank you @Jahnavi, maybe, we can create a bug to the target team for further help.

As you mentioned, the app setting WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING is no longer used to access the files in the storage from function app. And according to this MSDoc, it is required only with Elastic Premium and Consumption plan functions only.
It seems like there is a discrepancy with the document and the bicep functionality. I tried deploying it with P1V3 SKU but still the WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING missing parameter error raised as shown below.

Once I added the connection app setting, the deployment was successful as shown.
appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName'
          value: storage.name
        }
        {
        name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
        value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=jahkur001;AccountKey=xxxxxQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
          value: toLower(uniqueSampleFunctionName)
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION'
          value: '~14'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: applicationInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'python'
        }
        {
          name: 'EventHubConn__fullyQualifiedNamespace'
          value: '${eventHubNamespaceName}.servicebus.windows.net'
        }
]



As a workaround, you can try from the Portal side once the deployment is done by visiting environment variables under settings.
Remove the app setting WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and restart the app.

If still the issue persists, raise a support request to the Microsoft team as it is related to the feature discrepancy.
